# Provide same or blank ID to SVG object

Tags: javascript, svg, null

Can I give a blank or identical ID to multiple SVG objects with no ill effects?

The reason I ask is that I have the following function top draw a line:

```
    function createLine( id, x1, y1, x2, y2, color, width ){
        var svgCanvas = document.getElementById( "svgCanvas" );
        var line  = document.createElementNS( svgNS, "line" );
        line.setAttributeNS( null, "id", id );
        line.setAttributeNS( null, "x1", x1 );
        line.setAttributeNS( null, "y1", y1 );
        line.setAttributeNS( null, "x2", x2 );
        line.setAttributeNS( null, "y2", y2 );
        line.setAttributeNS( null, "color", color );
        line.setAttributeNS( null, "stroke-width", width );
        svgCanvas.appendChild( line );
    }
```

The problem is that sometimes I drawn an important line that needs to have an ID, thus the `id` parameter. However, other times I am drawing lots of small, inconsequential lines that do not need to have an ID. I would like to give those lines the id of "" (blank) or null. I do not want to have a separate function, but use the same function for all lines. So, if I call this function repeatedly with arguments like:

```
createLine( null, 10, 10, 20, 20, "black", 1 );
```

will it create a problem?

Answer (score 1):

Why not just do?

```
if (id != null) {
  line.setAttributeNS( null, "id", id );
}
```

Comment: that is a possibility